# How to add parameter to canned SCCM Report

Tags: sql, sccm

I am doing reporting in SCCM 2012 and I have software metering set up. One of the reports I use the most is the "Total usage for all metered software programs" canned report. I want to be able to add a parameter to the report to specify the collection. Then it will show data for a certain collection as opposed to the entire site.

I know how to set up the parameter in SQL Server 2012 Report Builder, but how do I modify the SQL queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue of access. I was unable to edit reports because the AD security role only granted me access to create reports. Elevated access is needed to edit the built-in reports.